# Java JTable dynamic population

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jtable

This is the first time I've ever tried using a Java Swing JTable, so I'm probably doing something silly.

I'm trying to dynamically update a JTable within a JFrame on a GUI, this is the code I've currently written:

```
 private void updateGUI(String input, DefaultTableModel model, int elements)  { //3 elements
    try {
        Object[] cellData = input.split("!\\*");
        Iterator it = Arrays.asList(cellData).iterator();
        int rowCount = cellData.length / numberOfElements;

        model.setRowCount(rowCount);

        for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < numberOfElements; j++) {
                model.setValueAt(it.next(), i, j);
            }

        }
    } catch (Exception uhoh) {
        System.out.println("Couldn't add new string to gui");
        uhoh.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Essentially, I pass the updateGUI function a String containing elements, separated by !*.  At the moment the data looks like this:

```
firstName!*123456!*lastName
```

This then gets split up into the Object[], and I'm currently using an iterator to put it into the table cells.

However, I keep getting `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 27 >=27` being thrown, so it looks I'm doing something wrong with the cell generation/population.

I'm sure there is a much better way of doing this, but after reading through a few examples, I'm still a bit puzzled.

Any suggestions or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: if you want to get data from database and create jtable dynamically refer this http://java4practices.blogspot.in/2012/12/create-and-view-database-table-in-java.html#more

Comment: what is numberOfElement? you should use some object orientation rather than a string.., and you are using an iterator without checking if it hasNext()

Comment: @GaneshRengarajan i don't like the view call directly bd :(

Comment: The data isn't coming from a database, it's coming from another internal function.

Comment: Number of elements is basically how many columns there are, so in this case it's 3, as it's firstname, int value, lastname

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 2) A `DefaultTableModel` offers some great methods to get around typical 'dynamic' problems with tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way I found to do this is to write a custom `TableModel`. I've written many of them and they not that difficult when you get your head around them. Given the code you posted you've have this message.

Derive your `TableModel` class from `AbstractTableModel`. This will handle the registration of any model listeners (one of which will be your `JTable`). Then on insert you need to call `fireXXX()` to notify all the listeners that there is new data. From your example code where you are replacing all the data this would be `fireTableDataChanged()`.

Comment: Thanks Dobbo.

Any recommended reading on doing that, or shall I just have a Google? :)

Thanks

Comment: @tony, The easiest way is to figure out why you get the Exception. There is something wrong with your math or your data. Creating a custom TableModel won't fix this. I suggest you first try the code with the String you posted in your question. That is get one row of data to work. Then try with two rows. Finally check to see what happens if your string does not contain items that is a multiple of 3.

Comment: @Tony Just Google for some examples.  It's so long ago since I coded my first table model that I really can't remember what I used as an example.  And @camickr does have a point about the exception, you will need to fix that. I don't know if that is being thrown in the `setValueAt() or `next()`.`

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the Glazedlists project: http://www.glazedlists.com/

It solves this and a lot more in a very easy to use way. Documentation on your specific case can be found at http://www.glazedlists.com/propaganda/features#TOC-Easy-TableModels